# Spheres appearing upon baking in particles system

Tags: animation, particles, baking

Im making a tentacle-like render and I want to see whats it looking like at the center so that i may convert it to mesh later on, but there are these spheres appearing after i click bake due to which i dont have a clear view.

Is there a way we turn this off? Im really just an amateur with this though...

Here is the image:
[image]

Comment: These look like halos, which are something that the emitter particle systems release. Are you sure that you dont have an emitter system enabled? Try and give us the file using https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Since you have "baking in particles system" in the title of your question, I'm quite sure @Relevred is right assuming those are halos. What is your particle system supposed to do?